# how to change the back button of NavigationBar

Tags: react-native, navigationbar

I am working on a React Native app which using [ex-navigation](https://github.com/exponentjs/ex-navigation). Now I have a window which have two modes: edit and view. When it is in edit mode, the left button of the navigation shows a check icon. Once the user press the check button then it switch to view mode, and the left button show back arrow icon. Anyone knows how to implement that using ex-navigation. If it's impossible for ex-navigation to do that, any other navigation lib can do? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use renderRight or renderLeft to control how the left or right buttons look like and function. For example from the documentation you can use this as example:

```
    class AboutScreen extends React.Component {
        static route = {
           navigationBar: {
           title: 'Title goes here',
           renderRight: (route, props) => <SignOutButton name={route.params.name} />
     }
   }

   // ...
 }
```

which will put a "sign out" button on the right.